# jquery access image width -- why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am somewhat new to Jquery but I feel complete failure here at not being able to do this.  I'm sure its something stupid but I have been at this for far too long.

So if I have html as such...

```
<div class="lightbox-image">
    <img src="http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64558.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

Why does this in my Jquery file generate a 'null' in the alert box?

```
alert($('.lightbox-image img'));
```

Shouldn't the alert box have something in it such as 'object'?

I have been on Jsfiddle and it still doesn't work.  I know I am missing something stupid so I apologize in advance for my naivety.  Thanks a lot!

- Nate

EDIT:

```
alert($('.lightboximage img'));
alert($('.lightboximage img').width());
$('.lightboximage img').load(function() {
    alert( $(this).width() );
});
```

This code generates an object on the first alert and a 0 on the next two alerts.  Why is this?  I know the image exists and JSfiddle says that its width is 825...

Comment: This should always return an object. Be sure on jsfiddle that you choose jQuery and not another library.

Comment: I got it working correctly on JSfiddle only to find the exact same implementation does not work on my live site.  I keep getting a value of 0 for the width of the image.  I've tried doing something where it only looks for the width once the image is loaded and that didn't work either.  I can't figure this out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.lightboximage img').width(100);
```

This works for me... I did notice that your image wasnt properly being retrieved from the server (401)

http://jsfiddle.net/uuuwU/

Comment: Sorry typo.  It still doesn't work with the lightboximage on both or lightbox-image on both.

Comment: The wrong selector may not be the issue, jQuery() always returns an object no matter if it found something or not

Comment: Hmm..maybe what happened is that I used an image from my testing server and it couldn't find a link to from js fiddle since its password protected?  I could still see the image because I was logged in.  Regardless...that does work, thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Molle I am still getting a null when I try to return the width of my object in my Jquery file.  What might be the problem?

Comment: If you get a `null` on $object.width() $object did not contain any elements(your selector didn't match any). If you get a 0 the image is not completely loaded yet.

Comment: I get a 0 for the image inside the .load command.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me, I have updated citizen conn script to output the width on the page, looks all good:

[http://jsfiddle.net/uuuwU/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/uuuwU/2/)